# How can my react-form directly send to my email?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so currently I'm trying to create my web app using react-bootstrap and now I have a form component and I want it to be able to send form response to my client email. How can I do it ? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into EmailJS
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/

Also there’s a great step-by-step guide that takes you through exactly what you need it for
https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/mailtrap.io/blog/react-send-email/amp/

Comment: Please don't just add links in your answer but take the most important content from the link and provide it as part of your answer. The link may end up dead anytime in the future and then your answer won't help others

Comment: Okay that makes sense, will know for future.